# Can I avoid float elements shifting when I resize my browser?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am new to the world of coding as well as CSS and have noticed that when I resize my browser, all my float elements move to say the right and the user is forced to scroll horizontally to view say the menu.

Firstly is there a need to prevent float elements not changing their position?

Secondly, is there a way I can avoid this if I should be preventing it?

Comment: Encapsulate your layout in a fixed-width container, so that it doesn't change size when the window does, which prevents reflowing of the layout.

Comment: Try to position the divs, if present, to absolute.

Comment: Although a work in progress (though pretty much abandoned), is [this](http://goo.gl/fbbps)  something you are trying to accomplish? Just move the boxes around then re-size the browser. Edit: was built to be used in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Shaz - Not really. I am trying to understand why my float elements shift/change positions when I resize my browser and whether I should place them a in a fixed container as Marc B suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Floats are a pain in the butt.  Primarily because of the one browser that refuses to follow the universal web standards.  Yeah, that one.

There are a million and one tricks to avoid these problems.  I tell my team to follow these steps:

1. Use absolutely positioned elements sparingly.  If you position based on another element, things can "auto-adjust" but not so much when things are mathematically glued to one spot.  They have their place, just not on every element on a page.
2. Consider a "reset" or grid-based CSS layout.  I personally prefer [960 Grids](http://www.960.gs)  They take the guesswork out of the various different browsers.  Will IE push your padding out?  Will the IE-specific padding be too much or too little with Firefox?  With a reset and/or a grid, it's not as big a deal.
3. When doing percentages (which I personally really like) remember that browser generally don't use math where 1 + 1 = 2.  That is to say, if you have a 1000 pixel space and you do two 50% columns side by side, chances are very good one is going to push itself below the other.  Why?  Because floats, margins, borders, etc. add up, and all differently in different browsers.  So, think that .9 + .9 = 2 when you design.  Does it work all the time?  Nope.  But it's a start.
4. Test, test, test.  Things like browsershots, Adobe Browser Labs, etc are your friend.  Use them constantly to ensure you're putting out good quality code that looks consistent across all platforms.
5. Keep it simple.  You might be working on a project that dictates 100 different style sheets covering every single version of every browser.  Most of us work on real-world projects with real-world budgets...that means you have to deploy quickly and efficiently.  Use good quality w3 compliant code and quality CSS and you can completely avoid hacks.

Comment: @bpeterson76 - Thanks. I know that articles and answers can be subjective however I am curious to know when would I use positioned elements over float elements.

Comment: @bpeterson76 - I had a look at 960 however am baffled on how I can use it. Do I download a specific template? For example I had a look at grids.heroku.com however am unsure how the column sizes, etc make a difference to my layout

Comment: Grids are a pretty basic concept.  Draw a grid on your screen...generally using 12 or 16 (but can be more or less) columns.  Everything must fit into those columns.  In the case of a 960 grid (960 pixels wide) each column of a 12 grid layout would be 80 pixels.  Want something to be 160 pixels wide?  Then it's a "grid_2" or two column wide element.  There are generators out there that are great, just think them through before you start writing code.

Comment: @Peanuts, on the absolutely positioned element, my rule of thumb is to only use when you absolutely need that functionality.  Basic positioning can be accomplished via relative positioning 99% of the time.  Use floats for elements that must sit on top of others (with z-index help) or for elements that sit askew of a container.  When you have to modify a layout, relatively positioned elements flow with their parents so modification isn't as painful.  With absolute, you have to change ever top and left declaration, and that can get old really fast.

Comment: @bpeterson76 - Thanks. So when you say that the column is 80 pixels, I assume it is 80 pixels wide. So do you mean to say elements must fit in a width of 80 pixels? If so, am having a hard time imagining how I could achieve that.

Comment: @peanuts, in multiples of 40 (or whatever your chosen number of columns/actual grid width equals, i.e. 12 columns/960pixels = 40 pixels per column)  Each column has a style, plus there are styles that cover two columns, three, four, etc.  You determine the proper multiple of columns to make your design work.  You can even download photoshop and illustrator templates to design on so you get it perfect from the start.  Here's an example of the various defined widths:  http://960.gs/demo.html

Comment: @bpeterson76 - When would you say a need is absolute to use absolute positioning? In a previous post I had at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102448/how-do-i-line-up-css-elements-is-there-a-tool-i-can-use, it was suggested I stay away from position and use floats since position can cause issues with most browsers.

Comment: @bpeterson76 - Sorry for my noobness. You completely lost me at `multiples of 40`.

Comment: John Sico did a great job explaining how to make something like that work.  Think in terms of containers...one around the site, one around the header, one around the logo, etc.  The only time you have likely consider absolute elements is when they have to break out of those containers.  We're not doing print design here, so you have to think in terms of how to present on a screen that could be from 100 pixels wide to 10,000....it's why UI is actually an art.

Comment: @bpeterson76 - Thanks. I think I understand the concept of containers however seem to misunderstand the concept of relative. For example in the code below, is it safe to assume if I have footer `position: relative;` it would be relative to content or is it relative to rightcol?

`<div id="content">
  <div id="innercontent">
   Text
  </div>
  
  <div id="rightcol">
   Text
  </div>
 </div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you figure out if you want to support differing resolutions, depending on your target audience. Elements moving around isn't necessarily a bad thing, and planning in advance how you want your site to layout depending on viewport size could be important.

If you can't find a fixed-width, "one layout to rule them all" that works for your needs, take a look at [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). For a more practical article on them, try [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)

The basic idea is that, using separate stylesheets that depend on size, you can basically display a different layout to the user depending on their viewport. Users resizing their browsers will be able to see the new layout dynamically as well.

Comment: I am curious about your statement that elements moving around isn't necessarily a bad thing. Why is that? When does it not matter?

Comment: Take a look at the responsive design article I linked, taking into account various devices that may be accessing your site could be important. (Again, depends largely on your target audience of course :) ).