# Problems with Float: Two Images switch places when browser is resized

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble with format when I resize my browser. i have two images that switch places, seemingly because they float. Is there a simple way for anyone to prevent those two images from switching?

This is my html file. When resizing the browser, the images `left.png` and "all.png" will switch places. I need them to stay where they are. How can I accomplish this?
[Visit here](http://web-dev.aws.sesameonline.net/ebook/pc/ebook.php?bid=1) to see how I want the images to act. Notice in the linked file how they do not switch places.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Hiragino Sans GB", "Microsoft YaHei", "WenQuanYi Micro Hei", sans-serif;
}

.os_mac {
  font-family: "ff-tisa-web-pro-1", "ff-tisa-web-pro-2", "Lucida Grande", "Hiragino Sans GB", "Hiragino Sans GB W3";
}

ul#book_list {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  -ms-filter: "progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
  background: #000;
}

#error-box {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 900;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: none;
}

#elmo_ebook_container {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  max-width: 1010px;
  max-height: none;
  height: 100%;
  /*container 100% height*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  *zoom: 1;
  /*ie6 quirksmode*/
  position: relative;
}

.nav,
#ebook_iframe_container {
  float: left;
}

#ebook_iframe {
  max-width: 576px;
  /*max width of iframe same as canvas*/
  max-height: 576px;
}

#ebook_iframe_dummy {
  left: 576px;
}

.nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 19.80198%;
  /*200/1010*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

li.line {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#ebook_iframe_container {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 60.39604%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#ebook_iframe {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.nav a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav a img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}


/*thumbnails carousel*/

#thumb {
  max-width: 1010px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  visibility: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 2px 0px;
}

#viewall {
  max-width: 1010px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  visibility: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 2px 0px;
}

.jcarousel-wrapper {
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}


/** Carousel **/

.jcarousel {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.jcarousel ul {
  width: 20000em;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.jcarousel li {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jcarousel img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jcarousel li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/** Carousel Controls **/

.jcarousel-control-prev,
.jcarousel-control-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4E443C;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font: 60px Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 120px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
}

.jcarousel-control-prev:hover,
.jcarousel-control-next:hover,
.jcarousel-control-close:hover {
  background: #d7352c;
}

.jcarousel-control-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 1%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4E443C;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 24px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
}

.jcarousel-control-prev {
  left: 15px;
}

.jcarousel-control-next {
  right: 15px;
}


/** Carousel Pagination **/

.jcarousel-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin: 0;
}

.jcarousel-pagination a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #4E443C;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #4E443C;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #4E443C;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #4E443C;
}

.jcarousel-pagination a.active {
  background: #4E443C;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #F0EFE7;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #F0EFE7;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #F0EFE7;
}


/*media query*/

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
(min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}

@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* Style adjustments for portrait mode goes here */
  .jcarousel-control-prev,
  .jcarousel-control-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    : #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font: 40px Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 80px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F0EFE7;
  }
  .nav,
  #ebook_iframe_container {
    float: none;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  li.line {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .nav a img {
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #ebook_iframe_container {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  #elmo_ebook_container {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    max-width: 1010px;
    max-height: none;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    /*container 100% height*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    *zoom: 1;
    /*ie6 quirksmode*/
  }
}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Style adjustments for landscape mode goes here */
  #elmo_ebook_container {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    /*container 100% height*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    *zoom: 1;
    /*ie6 quirksmode*/
  }
  .nav,
  #ebook_iframe_container {
    float: left;
  }
  #ebook_iframe {
    max-width: 576px;
    /*max width of iframe same as canvas*/
    max-height: 576px;
  }
  .nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 19.80198%;
    /*200/1010*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav li {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li.line {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  #ebook_iframe_container {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 60.39604%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  #ebook_iframe {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  .nav a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .nav a img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 160px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  /* landscape styles here */
}


/*for brwoser not support orientation*/

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  /* portrait styles here */
}

@media (max-width: 470px) {
  .nav,
  #ebook_iframe_container {
    float: none;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
  }
  .nav li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
  }
  li.line {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .nav a img {
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
  #ebook_iframe_container {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  #elmo_ebook_container {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    max-width: 1010px;
    max-height: none;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    /*container 100% height*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    *zoom: 1;
    /*ie6 quirksmode*/
  }
}

#loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}


/*fix ios canvas blink when tap*/

* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.bokeh {
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.bokeh li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bokeh li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  background: #00C176;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
  transform-origin: 50% 250%;
  -webkit-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.bokeh li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  background: #FF003C;
  -webkit-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
  transform-origin: -150% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.bokeh li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
  background: #FABE28;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
  transform-origin: 50% -150%;
  -webkit-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.bokeh li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 50%;
  left 0;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  background: #88C100;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
  transform-origin: 250% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rota {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rota {
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rota {
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rota {
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rota {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.if {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}


/*------*/

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}


/**
    * Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
    */

audio,
canvas,
video {
  display: inline-block;
}


/**
    * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
    * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
    */

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}


/**
    * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9.
    * Hide the `template` element in IE, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
    */

[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Base
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
    * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
    * user zoom.
    */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
    * Remove default margin.
    */

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Links
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
    */

a {
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/**
    * Address `outline` inconsistency between Chrome and other browsers.
    */

a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}


/**
    * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
    */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Typography
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
    * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari 5, and Chrome.
    */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}


/**
    * Address styling not present in IE 8/9, Safari 5, and Chrome.
    */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}


/**
    * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari 5, and Chrome.
    */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/**
    * Address styling not present in Safari 5 and Chrome.
    */

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}


/**
    * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
    */

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}


/**
    * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
    */

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}


/**
    * Correct font family set oddly in Safari 5 and Chrome.
    */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}


/**
    * Improve readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers.
    */

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}


/**
    * Set consistent quote types.
    */

q {
  quotes: "\201C" "\201D" "\2018" "\2019";
}


/**
    * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
    */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}


/**
    * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
    */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Embedded content
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9.
    */

img {
  border: 0;
}


/**
    * Correct overflow displayed oddly in IE 9.
    */

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Figures
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari 5.
    */

figure {
  margin: 0;
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Forms
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
    */


/**
    * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9.
    * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
    */

legend {
  border: 0;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
    * 1. Correct font family not being inherited in all browsers.
    * 2. Correct font size not being inherited in all browsers.
    * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari 5, and Chrome.
    */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 3 */
  color: #666666;
}


/**
    * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
    * the UA stylesheet.
    */

button,
input {
  line-height: normal;
}


/**
    * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
    * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
    * Correct `button` style inheritance in Chrome, Safari 5+, and IE 8+.
    * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox 4+ and Opera.
    */

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}


/**
    * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
    * and `video` controls.
    * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
    * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
    * `input` and others.
    */

button,
html input[type="button"],

/* 1 */

input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* 3 */
}


/**
    * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
    */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}


/**
    * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
    * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
    */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 2 */
}


/**
    * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari 5 and Chrome.
    * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari 5 and Chrome
    * (include `-moz` to future-proof).
    */

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/**
    * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari 5 and Chrome
    * on OS X.
    */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/**
    * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
    */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/**
    * 1. Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9.
    * 2. Improve readability and alignment in all browsers.
    */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: top;
  /* 2 */
}


/* ==========================================================================
    Tables
    ========================================================================== */


/**
    * Remove most spacing between table cells.
    */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta content="no-cache" http-equiv "pragma"="">
  <meta content="on" http-equiv="cleartype">
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-touch-fullscreen">
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
  <meta content="black-translucent" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style">
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
  <title>Navigation Template</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ebook_wrapper.css"></link>
  <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.touchwipe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="ebook.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- BOOK SLIDER GOES HERE
    -->
  <!-- THIS IS THE CENTER CONTENT -->
  <!-- INTERACTIVE CONTENT GOES INTO THE IFRAME CONTAINER -->
  <div id="elmo_ebook_container" class="clearfix">
    <ul class="nav clearfix">
      <li class="fline">
        <a id="home" class="button" href="../index.php">
          <img alt="home" src="home.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="bottom_left" class="line">
        <a id="left" class="button" href="#">
          <img alt="left" src="left.png">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="ebook_iframe_container">
      <div id="ifcontainer" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;position:relative">
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav clearfix">
      <li id="top_right" class="fline">
        <a id="all" class="button" href="#">
          <img alt="all" src="all.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="bottom_right" class="line">
        <a id="right" class="button" href="#">
          <img alt="right" src="right.png">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- THIS IS THE END OF THE CENTER CONTENT -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) remove your HTML header in your post. 2) Include the related CSS

Comment: Either build a fiddle, or copy the relevant code here.  When your site is fixed, down, or broken, this question will have no value.

Comment: I've added the relevant CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I avoid float elements shifting when I resize my browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115960/can-i-avoid-float-elements-shifting-when-i-resize-my-browser)